# responsive dc.js chart is taking over the whole window

Tags: dc.js

I'm having trouble making my chart responsive, I'm trying to apply the same example with DC.js and Crossfilter that is at this link: [resizing-series](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web-src/resizing/resizing-series.html).

The chart is responsive, however, there are some bugs when interacting with the tables I have. For example, when I click on either the graph or any of the tables, the graph becomes very large, occupying the entire screen. As shown in the image below:

[image]
[image]

When I leave the screen split with `Console`, the graph is rendered responsively, as I change the screen size the size of the graph is also changed, however, if I leave`Console` the graph remains occupying the entire the screen and does not return to the default initial size shown in the first image.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how to tell me how to fix these bugs? I couldn't understand why this is happening.

Thnaks in advance.

```js
var composite = dc.compositeChart('#composite');
var vendedorTable = dc.dataTable("#vendedores");
var citiesTable = dc.dataTable("#cities");

function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
  return {
    top: function(N) {
      return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
        return d.value.totalAno > 1e-3 ||
          d.value.totalHomologo > 1e-3;
      }).slice(0, N);
    }
  };
}

var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bernalvinicius/3cece295bc37de1697e7f83418e7fcc9/raw/a5820379ec6eae76ee792495cc5dd1685c977a73/vendedores.json';
d3.json(url).then(function(data) {

  data.forEach(d =>
    Object.assign(d, {
      mes: d.Month,
      atual: d.Vendas_Ano,
      passado: d.Vendas_Ant
    })
  );
  var cf = crossfilter(data);

  vendedorDim = cf.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.vendnm;
  });
  var vendedorGroup = vendedorDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

  citiesDim = cf.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.zona;
  });
  var citiesGroup = citiesDim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

  var dim = cf.dimension(dc.pluck('mes')),
    grp1 = dim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('atual')),
    grp2 = dim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('passado'));
  var minMonth = dim.bottom(1)[0].mes;
  var maxMonth = dim.top(1)[0].mes;

  var all = cf.groupAll();

  dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count")
    .dimension(cf)
    .group(all);

  function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    p.totalAno += +v.Vendas_Ano;
    p.totalHomologo += +v.Vendas_Ant;
    return p;
  }

  function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    p.totalAno -= v.Vendas_Ano;
    p.totalHomologo -= v.Vendas_Ant;
    return p;
  }

  function reduceInitial() {
    return {
      totalAno: 0,
      totalHomologo: 0,
    };
  }

  // Fake Dimension
  rank = function(p) {
    return ""
  };

  // Chart by months
  composite
    .width(600)
    .height(300)
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 12]))
    .yAxisLabel("")
    .xAxisLabel("Month")
    .legend(dc.legend().x(500).y(0).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .compose([
      dc.lineChart(composite)
      .dimension(dim)
      .colors('steelblue')
      .group(grp1, "Currently Year"),
      dc.lineChart(composite)
      .dimension(dim)
      .colors('darkorange')
      .group(grp2, "Last Year")
    ])
    .brushOn(true);

  composite.brush().extent([-0.5, data.length + 1.5])
  composite.extendBrush = function(brushSelection) {
    if (brushSelection) {
      vendedorTable.filter(null);
      vendedorDim.filter(null);
      citiesTable.filter(null);
      citiesDim.filter(null);
      const point = Math.round((brushSelection[0] + brushSelection[1]) / 2);
      return [
        point - 0.5,
        point + 0.5
      ];
    }
  };

  // Sales Table
  vendedorTable.width(500)
    .height(480)
    .dimension(remove_empty_bins(vendedorGroup))
    .group(rank)
    .columns([function(d) {
        return d.key;
      },
      function(d) {
        return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }) + '€';
      },
      function(d) {
        return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }) + '€';
      }
    ])
    .sortBy(function(d) {
      return d.value.totalAno
    })
    .order(d3.descending)

  // Cities Table
  citiesTable.width(500)
    .height(480)
    .dimension(remove_empty_bins(citiesGroup))
    .group(rank)
    .columns([function(d) {
        return d.key;
      },
      function(d) {
        return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalAno * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }) + '€';
      },
      function(d) {
        return Number(Math.round(d.value.totalHomologo * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 2
        }) + '€';
      }
    ])
    .sortBy(function(d) {
      return d.value.totalAno
    })
    .order(d3.descending)

  // Sales click events
  vendedorTable.on('pretransition', function(table) {
    table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
      .on('click', function(d) {
        let filters = table.filters().slice();
        if (filters.indexOf(d.key) === -1)
          filters.push(d.key);
        else
          filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
        if (filters.length === 0)
          vendedorDim.filter(null);
        else
          vendedorDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
            return filters.indexOf(d) !== -1;
          })
        table.replaceFilter([filters]);

        citiesTable.filter(null);
        citiesDim.filter(null);
        composite.filter(null);

        dc.redrawAll();
      });
    let filters = table.filters();
    table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
      .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
  });

  // Cities click events
  citiesTable.on('pretransition', function(table) {
    table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
      .on('click', function(d) {
        let filters = table.filters().slice();
        if (filters.indexOf(d.key) === -1)
          filters.push(d.key);
        else
          filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
        if (filters.length === 0)
          citiesDim.filter(null);
        else
          citiesDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
            return filters.indexOf(d) !== -1;
          })
        table.replaceFilter([filters]);

        vendedorTable.filter(null);
        vendedorDim.filter(null);
        composite.filter(null);

        dc.redrawAll();
      });
    let filters = table.filters();
    table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
      .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
  });


  dc.renderAll();

  // reset functions
  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null);
    citiesTable.filter(null);
    citiesDim.filter(null);
    composite.filter(null);

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

  $('#resetTable').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null);
    citiesTable.filter(null);
    citiesDim.filter(null);
    composite.filter(null);

    dc.redrawAll();
  });

  $('#resetTable2').on('click', function() {
    vendedorTable.filter(null);
    vendedorDim.filter(null);
    citiesTable.filter(null);
    citiesDim.filter(null);
    composite.filter(null);

    dc.redrawAll();
  });


  /****************************************************************************/
  // Functions to handle responsive

  var adjustX = 10,
    adjustY = 40;

  apply_resizing(composite, adjustX, adjustY, function(composite) {
    composite.legend().x(window.innerWidth - 200);
  });

  var find_query = function() {
    var _map = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&').map(function(a) {
      return a.split('=');
    }).reduce(function(p, v) {
      if (v.length > 1)
        p[v[0]] = decodeURIComponent(v[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
      else
        p[v[0]] = true;
      return p;
    }, {});
    return function(field) {
      return _map[field] || null;
    };
  }();

  var resizeMode = find_query('resize') || 'widhei';

  function apply_resizing(composite, adjustX, adjustY, onresize) {
    if (resizeMode === 'viewbox') {
      composite
        .width(300)
        .height(200)
        .useViewBoxResizing(true);
      d3.select(composite.anchor()).classed('fullsize', false);
    } else {
      adjustX = adjustX || 0;
      adjustY = adjustY || adjustX || 0;
      composite
        .width(window.innerWidth - adjustX)
        .height(window.innerHeight - adjustY);
      window.onresize = function() {
        if (onresize) {
          onresize(composite);
        }
        composite
          .width(window.innerWidth - adjustX)
          .height(window.innerHeight - adjustY);

        if (composite.rescale) {
          composite.rescale();
        }
        composite.redraw();
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#composite {
  padding: 10px;
}

.dc-table-group {
  visibility: collapse;
}

tr.dc-table-row.sel-rows {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.brush .custom-brush-handle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/puzzle.png">
<!-- bootstrap.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- bootstrap-theme.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- dc.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.8/dc.css">
<!-- jquery.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- bootstrap.js -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- d3.v5.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<!-- crossfilter.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>
<!-- dc.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.8/dc.js"></script>

<title>12</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div id="composite"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div style="padding: 20px;;" class="row marginClass">
          <h4 class="pull-left" id="Introduction">
            <small>Fictitious company data | Drilldown Example |</small>
          </h4>
          <h6 class="dc-data-count" style="float: left;margin-left:5px;">
            <span>
                            <span class="filter-count"></span> selected from
            <span class="total-count"></span> records |
            <a id="reset"> Reset </a>
            </span>
          </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <table class="table" id="vendedores">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Sales</th>
                <th>Current Year</th>
                <th>Last Year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <table class="table" id="cities">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Current Year</th>
                <th>Last Year</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for posting an example! The bug doesn't show up in the SO code snippet feature unless you go to full page mode. I found [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bernalvinicius/kanm158j/20/) easier to work with.

Note: this is a complete rewrite of my previous answer, which was not clear.

#### 1. Using `ResizeObserver`

*updated 4/28/20*

As of Safari 13.1 (released March 24 2020) all modern browsers support [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver). This is the cleanest way to detect chart resizing.

I recommend

1. Use a top-down layout such as flexbox or grid to position the  divs for your charts
2. Use `ResizeObserver` to determine when the div has changed size
3. Tell the charts to detect the chart div size using `.width(null).height(null)`

There is currently [one resizing example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/resizing/resizing-scatter-flexbox-observer.html) that does this.

The special value `null` tells the chart to make the SVG node the same size as its parent div:

```
chart1.width(null)
    .height(null)
```

The callback uses a helper function to disable transitions, because transitions just slow resizing down and make it look clunky:

```
const callback = chart => entries => {
    redraw_chart_no_transitions(
        chart
            .width(null)
            .height(null)
            .rescale());
    };
```

Setting up the observer looks like

```
new ResizeObserver(callback(chart1)).observe(d3.select('#test1').node());
```

Please see the example for more details.

#### 2. Using `window.onresize`

The other [resizing examples](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/resizing) watch for `window.onresize` because until recently that was the only efficient, reliable cross-browser way to detect changes.

They calculate chart sizes based on the window size, which works well if your layout is bottom-up, e.g. using the default `float: left` layout.

Here is the function which sets this up:

```
function apply_resizing(chart, adjustX, adjustY, onresize) {
    if(!Array.isArray(chart))
        chart = [chart];
    if(!isNaN(adjustX))
        adjustX = (dx => x => x-dx)(adjustX);
    adjustX = adjustX || (x => x);
    if(!isNaN(adjustY))
        adjustY = (dy => y => y-dy)(adjustY);
    adjustY = adjustY || adjustX || (y => y);
    chart.forEach(c => c.width(adjustX(window.innerWidth))
                  .height(adjustY(window.innerHeight)));
    window.onresize = function () {
        if (onresize) {
            chart.forEach(onresize);
        }
        chart.forEach(c => {
            c.width(adjustX(window.innerWidth))
                .height(adjustY(window.innerHeight));
            if (c.rescale) {
                c.rescale();
            }
        });
        redraw_chart_no_transitions(chart);
    };
}
```

A single chart can be initialized like so:

```
apply_resizing(chart, 20);
```

This fills the window but makes the chart 20 pixels less wide.

The function can also take multiple charts in an array, and adjustment functions to support complicated layouts, like one where two charts should split the window vertically:

```
apply_resizing([heatmapChart, barChart], 20, y => y/2-fudge);
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, I'm going to do a better research on how to use window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth, I'm still really confused about that. I don't know if it helps, but I put the code in JSFiddle to see if is possibl to reproduce the bugs: https://jsfiddle.net/bernalvinicius/kanm158j/20/
Thanks again

Comment: The fiddle helps - easy to repro the issue! - but it doesn't show how you want to do the layout. Is the idea that the composite line chart should resize only horizontally, to fill from the left edge of the window to the right edge, but always stay the same height? Or do you want it to resize vertically as well?

Comment: Here's a [fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/uf0naepk/2/) with resizing only applied to the width. Basically I have changed all the vertical calculations not to use `window.innerHeight` but use 300 instead. And also initialize the chart width using `window.innerWidth` (as well as the resizing bits you already had). If this is what you want I'll edit my answer to put in that info.

Comment: Hey Gordon, sorry for the delay in replying, I was meeting here at the company. Initially the horizontal adjustment is fine. This is what I needed for now to show my boss, thanks again.

Comment: Hi Gordon, this method has been working really well for me. I have one issue though. I have a dashboard that uses this pattern for a heat map, bubble chart, row chart and pie chart. To get it to work, I have to comment out the .rescale() in the callback.

I have another dashboard with a composite chart with a specified x domain that will resize except for the xaxis line, however if I uncomment the .rescale() it works.

Not a big issue, I just have two callbacks.

Comment: Thanks @AriBeauDyball! Yes it is annoying that rescale is sometimes necessary and sometimes not. I wasn’t aware that it is sometimes harmful; I guess I always start without it and add it if needed. I wish this could be determined automatically.