# dc.js heatmap - make the top row rects to begin at y="0"

Tags: dc.js

I have a dc.js heatmap working:

[image]

But I want to add grid lines to it, like so:

[image]

You can see that the lines to not match up with the bottom edges of the rects. Inserting the lines themselves is easy, you just start at zero and add 11 lines based on the height of the rects, which in this case will always be 11 / chart.effectiveHeight().

The reason they do not match up, seems to be that the top rect row does not always start at 0, instead, there seems to be a random(?) y position that the chart starts at, this will change with the height of the chart container, eg this y position starts at 5:

[image]

If it was consistent, then I could just start appending lines from that number instead of 0, but it is not. I have tried a couple of hacky work arounds, however I am unsure as to how to get the y position of all the rects after they are available in the DOM.

Interestingly the demo heatmap does not have this issue:

[image]

Here is the code for the heatmap:

```
 const heat_map = dc.heatMap('#heatmap');
  heat_map
    .width(0)
    .height(0)
    .margins(margins)
    .dimension(hm_dim)
    .group(hm_group)
    .keyAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[0]; })
    .valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })
    .colorAccessor(function(d) { return +d.value; })
    .colors(color_scale)
    .calculateColorDomain()
    .yBorderRadius(0)
    .xBorderRadius(0)
  heat_map.render();
```

Is there a way to force the rects to begin at 0? Or get the random y position for the top rows? I did have a look at the source code but got a bit lost. Also I thought about creating a false group that would include each rect in the grid, and the grid lines could then be rect borders, but I thought that was a bit heavy handed.

Comment: Did you try styling the rects’ `stroke-width` using CSS? Seems like it might be an easy solution but I don’t know if it would look perfect. It should also be possible to measure from the bottom.

Comment: I did, but the issue is that not each space in the grid is guaranteed to have data, so creating a fake group that will put a rect in each grid space, then adding css to the rects could be a solution, but it seems a little heavy handed when I just want to append 10 lines.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you meant about the fake group! I agree that’s messy. I explained why there is extra space in my answer below. You have two options: 1. align the lines to the bottom of the chart instead of the top, using the `.margins()` or 2. calculate the chart height so there is no extra space, as described below. If you can’t figure it out, I’ll try to add another answer soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Outlining the cells using CSS

It's easy to outline the cells using CSS:

```
rect.heat-box {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: black;
}
```

[image: heatmap with outlines]

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/8s03trny/8/).

However, as you point out, this only works if all the cells have values; crossfilter will not create the empty ones and I agree it would be absurd fill them in using a fake group just for some lines.

So, to answer your original question...

#### Why is there a gap at the top of the chart?

The heatmap calculates an integer size for the cells, and there may be space left over (since the space doesn't divide perfectly).

It's kind of nasty but the heatmap example avoids having extra space by calculating the width and height for the chart using the count of cells in each dimension:

```
chart
  .width(45 * 20 + 80)
  .height(45 * 5 + 40)
```

The default margins are `{top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 30}` so this allocates 45x45 pixels for each cell and adds on the margins to get the right chart size.

Since the heatmap in this example draws 20 columns by 5 rows, it will calculate the cell width and height as 45.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yep, it was the height(0) and width(0) that were causing the issue. If you are explicit with the height and width it seems that the leftmost and topmost rects will start at their y/x = "0" position. I just needed to do some math using the container dimensions, intended margins and number of grid spaces to get the explicit height and width values before creating the chart. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Answer for Responsive/Resizable Charts**

I am revisiting this question after rewriting my heatmap chart to be responsive - using the "ResizeObserver" method outlined in the [dc.js resizing examples](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/resizing/resizing-scatter-flexbox-observer.html) and Gordon's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60279265/responsive-dc-js-chart-is-taking-over-the-whole-window)

While specifying the chart width and height for the heatmap in Gordon's answer still works, it does not combine well with the resizing method because resized charts will have their .width and .height set to 'null'. Which means that this rounding issue will reoccur and the heat boxes will be again be offset by a random integer x or y value of anywhere between 0 and 5 (unless you want to write a custom resizing function for heatmaps).

The alternative answer is relatively simple and can be determined by selecting just one heat-box element in the heatmap.

The vertical offset value for the heat boxes is the remainder value when the heat-box y attribute is divided by the heat-box height attribute.

```
const heatbox_y = heat_map.select('.heat-box').attr('y);
const heatbox_height = heat_map.select('.heat-box').attr('height')
const vertical_offset = heatbox_y % heatbox_height
```

The modulus % will return the remainder.

The horizontal offset can be determined in the same way.

Thus you can append lines to the chart at regular intervals determined by the heatbox_height + the vertical_offset values.

This will work if you pick any heat-box in the chart, and so it is suitable for instances like this where you cannot guarantee that there will be a heat-box at each x or y level. And it means that you are free to set your chart height and width to 'null' if needed.

[image]